# How stop navigation on back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stop navigation on clicking back button of the browser

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e){
    realTimePersonalizationTest(e);
});

function realTimePersonalizationTest(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

But this code is not working. it is navigating back to the previous page.

Comment: beforeunload is special type of event, you can have preventDefault in that.
The function is expected to return a String which will be prompted to user when he/she tries to navigate back. That's all you can do.

Comment: Why do you want to restrict navigation? What is the reason and final purpose? Probably, together we can find a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Preventing the navigation on clicking back button sounds wrong.
The only thing you can do with `beforeunload` event is to return a string in order to prompt user before he leaves the page.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e){
    return "Are you sure? Please, don't leave.";
});
```

For example, open [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w1a36yae/) and try to close it.

Most probably, any other implementations will not not be supported by browsers due to security reasons. Back button is "hardware" button which is supposed to be always navigating to the previous page.

You can implement this restriction server-side using redirects, session variables etc.
However, why does one need to disable this behaviour? I strongly believe that there should be another, more consistent, browser and user-friendly solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you needn't to support old IE browsers than this code snippet will work for you.

```
var path = 'Name of your page';
//Like for www.Test.com/abc.html write abc.html in path variable
history.pushState(null, null, path + window.location.search);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
    history.pushState(null, null, path + window.location.search);
});
```

I hope that will work for you.. for more info check http://www.cheezycode.com/2015/08/how-to-stop-browser-back-using-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use popstate event to detect browser back button

```
      window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  window.location.assign("www.google.com");
};
```

then inside this code locate to your current page instead of window.location.assign("www.google.com");